# How to return Success data after update in firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, angular

I tried to return data after update in firebase but it is displaying as `undefined`

```
    test().then((res) => {
        alert(res);
      });

    test() {
    var fredNameRef = new Firebase('https://docs-examples.firebaseio.com/samplechat/users/fred/name');

    var onComplete = function(error) {
      if (error) {
        return error;
      } else {
        return "success";
      }
    };
    fredNameRef.update({ first: 'Wilma', last: 'Flintstone' }, onComplete);
    }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [`onComplete` callback](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/firebase/update.html) is used to check for errors during the update, not to receive the data.

The [Firebase SDK surfaces update first locally](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/retrieving-data.html#section-event-guarantees), and then if successful it fires the `onComplete` callback.

In your case you want to save the data and then listen for the update using the `.on()` method.

```
var fredNameRef = new Firebase('https://docs-examples.firebaseio.com/samplechat/users/fred/name');

fredNameRef.on('value', function(snap) {
  console.log(snap.val());
});

fredNameRef.update({ first: 'Wilma', last: 'Flintstone' });
```

After the `.update()` method is executed, it will trigger the `.on()` method.

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick reply..it works fine now.. i need some clarification on `once` method. what happens if i use `once` instead of `on` ?

Comment: Same thing except it only fires once rather than for every update while connected.

Comment: in offline`update()` will trigger `ref.on('value', function(snapshot){});`....! is this behaviour is Right....??  It looks like bug. Please explain if i am wrong..!

Comment: The Firebase SDK link has moved to --> https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data